# Angular 14 SSR crashing with id undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, angular-universal

Recently we have upgraded our angular version from 13 to 14. Also the firebase from 8 to 9 modular. Everything looks fine at our local. After uploading to server and waiting for around 6 hours we get something like this error and the SSR crash. We have to run the `npm run serve:ssr` again to run the website.

Any idea how do I fixed this issue?

This kind of error used to come before also while we were running at angular v13 but it never crash. Now it seems alot.

[image]

server.ts

```
(global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');
(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/projectfolder/browser');
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(distFolder, 'index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template.toString());
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['DOMTokenList'] = win.DOMTokenList;
global['Node'] = win.Node;
global['Text'] = win.Text;
global['HTMLElement'] = win.HTMLElement;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
global['getComputedStyle'] = win.getComputedStyle;

(global as any).self = {fetch: require('node-fetch')};



import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { environment } from './src/environments/environment';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/projectfolder/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));
  // '/lm/**',
  let routesPath = ['/invite', '/invite/**','/lm', '/dashboard', '/dashboard/**', '/public/**', '/public', '/pre'];
  server.get(routesPath, (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req);
    res.sendFile(distFolder + '/index.html');
  });
  
  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || environment.PORT;
  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on https://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```